# Python rounding up float number

Tags: python

I need to get results like these:

```
2.1421 => 2.15
2.1401 => 2.15
2.14   => 2.14
```

Comment: So you want to round up to the nearest `0.01`?

Comment: Use `round(num, 2)`

Comment: yes, but to add 1 to 2nd decimal even if 3rd is 0 except if no 3rd digit

Comment: the +0.005 trick doesn't work with 2.14... forget it.

Comment: Can't you just `math.ceil(num * 100) / 100.0`?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre it worked..  Thank u

Comment: @FirasSy actually Jerrybibo comment is the best.

Comment: oh yea for 2.14 not working

Comment: yes this worked 100% Thank you very much @Jerrybibo

Comment: Beware of floats not doing what you might expect... Test your algorithms against 2.45 and 2.85. Note that `format(2.45, '.20f')` returns 2.45000000000000017764 and `format(2.85, '.20f')` returns 2.85000000000000008882

Answer (score 0):

As @Jerrybibo mentioned, you'll need to use the ceil function, and to get the result to the nearest hundredths place, simply multiply your number by a hundred, run it through ceil and then divide that answer by 100. You can try it in IDLE.

```
>>> math.ceil(2.1421 * 100) / 100
2.15
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: I did not see that, actually...I had copied the answer from here and made it single line: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8866046/python-round-up-integer-to-next-hundred