# Rounding of a date to the nearest half year

Tags: python, datetime

I want to be able to round of the current date to the nearest(later/equal to) half a year in the format `DD MMM YYYY` in python.

**Example 1:** If today is `10 Jul 2019`, I want the output of my code to display `31 Dec 2019`.

**Example 2:**  If today is `15 Jan 2019`, I want the output to be `30 Jun 2019`.

Also, i want the months to be Jun/Dec (MMM), not 06 or 12.

I have imported the datetime package, but do not know how to go ahead. I am trying to use the round function, but not sure as well.

I have a code for my email: Please refer to the requirements for the half year ending DD MMM YYYY. i want the DD MMM YYYY to be autopopulated

Comment: Do you really want the nearest? You always want the output date to be later or equal than the input, right?

Comment: oh yes, thanks for pointing that out, later/equal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With help of this response [Python round up integer to next hundred](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8866046/python-round-up-integer-to-next-hundred) you could use something like this:

```
from datetime import datetime
from calendar import monthrange

def roundup(x, b=6):
    return x if x % b == 0 else x + b - x % b

def get_nearest_halfyear(date_str):
    d = datetime.strptime(date_str, '%d %b %Y')
    m = roundup(d.month)
    return datetime(year=d.year, month=m, day=monthrange(d.year, m)[-1] ).strftime('%d %b %Y')

for s in ['10 Jul 2019', '15 Jan 2019']:
    print('Please refer to the requirements for the half year ending {}.'.format(get_nearest_halfyear(s)))
```

Prints:

```
Please refer to the requirements for the half year ending 31 Dec 2019.
Please refer to the requirements for the half year ending 30 Jun 2019.
```

Comment: Thanks Andrej for the help but i am look out for something like this:

I have a code for my email: Please refer to the requirements for the half year ending DD MMM YYYY.

i want the DD MMM YYYY to be autopopulated

Comment: Thank you Andrej, really helped me! saviour

Answer (score 0):

you can do this by checking whthr `date.today().month//7 >0`. this will give which half of the year current day falls in and return last day of the half year accordingly.

```
from datetime import datetime,date
def get_nearest_halfyear(date_var):
    return date(date_var.year, 12, 31).strftime("%d %b %Y") if date_var.month//7>0 else date(date_var.year, 6, 30).strftime("%d %b %Y")
print('Please refer to the requirements for the half year ending {}.'.format(get_nearest_halfyear(date.today())))
```

> **output :**   Please refer to the requirements for the half year ending 31 Dec 2019.