# How can I program to print the next number of 2675.9439 which is divisible by 25 and print it out in python

Tags: python

Manual computation is
2675.9439

Next number will be 2700 which is divisible by 25

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour]. This seems like a homework question. Please read [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822/4518341) under "Asking about homework". Even if it's not homework, the same advice applies.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python round up integer to next hundred](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8866046/python-round-up-integer-to-next-hundred)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
math.ceil(2675.9439/25)*25
```