# python fixed digits rounding

Tags: python, python-2.7

Is there an function in python 2 that can do this?

```
1234 -> round(1234, 2) = 1200
1234 -> round(1234, 3) = 1230
12.34 -> round(12.34, 3) = 12.3
```

Basically the second number says the precision of the number and the everything behind should be rounded.

Based on the comment i came up with this:

```
def round_to_precision(x, precision):
    return int(round(x / float(10 ** precision))) * 10 ** precision
```

But this is still wrong, because i don't know the size of the numbers.

Comment: check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8866046/python-round-up-integer-to-next-hundred) site. This algorithm applies to all numbers

Comment: thank you. I made an edit, but there is still something wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution (written step by step for clarity).

```
import math

num_digits = lambda x: int((math.log(x, 10)) + 1)

def round(x, precision): 
    digits = num_digits(x) 
    gap = precision - digits
    x = x * (10 ** gap)
    x = int(x) 
    x = x / (10 ** gap)
    return x
```

results:

```
round(1234, 2) # 1200
round(1234, 3) # 1230
round(12.34, 3) # 12.3
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution:

```
def round_to_precision(x, precision):
    fmt_string = '{:.' + str(precision) + 'g}'
    return float(fmt_string.format(x))


print round_to_precision(1234, 2)
print round_to_precision(1234, 3)
print round_to_precision(12.34, 3)
```