# How can i round a number down to nearest hundred in python?

Tags: python

I'm dealing with the value of inputs.The input should be rounded down to nearest hundred. For example, if the input is 5398 euros, the input is determined using value 5300 euros.

Comment: `100*int(5398/100)` should do just that...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python round up integer to next hundred](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8866046/python-round-up-integer-to-next-hundred)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use either of these three ways (there may exist many more ways):

```
import math
print(math.floor(5398 / 100.00) * 100)
```

Output is `5300` as expected.

```
rounded = int(5398 / 100) * 100
print(rounded)
```

Still the output is `5300`.

```
import numpy
print(int(numpy.floor(5398 / 100.0) * 100))
```

The output is still `5300` :)

Have Fun :)

Comment: no need to use `numpy` for `floor`. that is in [`math.floor`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.floor) already.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that by taking the integer part of the number divided by 100 and then multiplying by 100:

```
rounded = int(your_number / 100) * 100
```