# How to round up to the next integer ending with 2 in Python?

Tags: python, math, rounding

Can you help me to round like the following?

```
10 -> 12
21 -> 22
22 -> 22
23 -> 32
34 -> 42
```

I tried answers from below, but all of them are rounding to next multiplier of a number:

[Round to 5 (or other number) in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2272149/round-to-5-or-other-number-in-python)

[Python round up integer to next hundred](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8866046/python-round-up-integer-to-next-hundred)

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please see: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import math
x = [10, 21, 22, 23, 34]

for n in x:
    print((math.ceil((n-2)/10)*10)+2)
```

outputs:

```
12
22
22
32
42
```

Comment: The parentheses around `math.ceil(...) * 10` are unnecessary.

Comment: @BrianMcCutchon Yes, but improve readability in my opinion

Comment: @couka For best readability, you could use a separate variable and add spaces, like `out = math.ceil((n-2)/10)*10 + 2; print(out)`

Comment: Well, readability vs shortness can be a trade-off and that's where the optimum is for me.

Answer (score 4):

You can compare the number mod 10 to 2; if less than or equal to 2, add `2 - num % 10` else add `12 - num % 10` to get to the nearest higher (or equal) number ending in 2:

```
def raise_to_two(num):
    if num % 10 <= 2:
        return num + 2 - num % 10
    return num + 12 - num % 10

print(raise_to_two(10))
print(raise_to_two(21))
print(raise_to_two(22))
print(raise_to_two(23))
print(raise_to_two(34))
```

Output:

```
12
22
22
32
42
```

Note (thanks to @MarkDickinson for pointing this out) that because the python modulo operator always returns a positive number if the second argument (to the right of `%` is positive), you can simplify the above to

```py
def raise_to_two(num):
    return num + (2 - num) % 10
```

The output remains the same

Comment: Just compare mod 2. If it is zero add 2, if it is one add 1.

Comment: @MichaelHofmann it's not rounding to the next multiple of 2, it's rounding to the next higher number which ends in 2.

Comment: You could get rid of the branching here and just return `num + (2 - num) % 10`

Comment: @MarkDickinson thanks for that - I should have tested it because I can never seem to remember which languages return negative results for modulo when one input is negative. I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 2):

this should also work.

```py
arr = [10, 21, 22, 23, 34]
for a in arr:
    b = ((a-3) // 10) * 10 + 12
    print(f"{a} -> {b}")
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the code:

```
 def round_by_two(number):
    unitOfDecena = number // 10
    residual = number % 10
    if residual == 2:
        requiredNumber = number
    elif residual > 2:
        requiredNumber = (unitOfDecena + 1)*10 + 2
    else:
        requiredNumber = unitOfDecena*10 + 2
    return requiredNumber
```