# how to round up to a multiple of 30 in python?

Tags: python, math

I need to round the user input up to the next 30, for example if the number entered was 27 I would need the output to be 30. or if they entered 33 the output would need to be 60. I don't even know where to start with this.

**like this:**

15-->30

1-->30

35-->60

56-->60

61-->90

43-->60

and so on with any input.

**thank you for the help**

[completed code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/autiI.png)

Comment: divide by 30, round up, multiply by 30.

Comment: Is the input always an integer?

Comment: This is mostly a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/8866046/270986 - just replace `100` with `30` in the answer of your choice.

Comment: Also, should an input of `60` round to `60` or to `90`? Which of those counts as the "next 30"?

Answer (score 1):

```
number = 35

# Integer division of the number by 30, add 1 and multiply by 30:
result = ((number - 1) // 30 + 1) * 30
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `math.ceil` like this:

```
int(math.ceil(yourNum / 30.0)) * 30
```

That is, rounding up the division of your number by 30, and then multiplying by 30.

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```py
import math


def round_next_multiple_of_30(input_number: int) -> int:
    return math.ceil(input_number / 30.0) * 30


assert round_next_multiple_of_30(15) == 30
assert round_next_multiple_of_30(1) == 30
assert round_next_multiple_of_30(35) == 60
assert round_next_multiple_of_30(61) == 90
```

Answer (score -1):

The next function may be use to round up to any base:

```
import math

def myround(x, base=30):
    return base * math.ceil(x/base)
```

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest to divide by 30, use `math.ceil()` to round up to the nearest integer, and multiply by 30 again:

```
import math
rounded_number = (math.ceil(unrounded_number / 30)) * 30
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is my solution:

```
import math

def next30(num):
    return math.ceil(num / 30.0) * 30

number = float(input("Number: "))
print(next30(number))
```